# How can I solve a "messaging/registration-token-not-registered" error in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is the documentation for the error:

> The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons, including:
>
> - The client app unregistered itself from FCM.
> - The client app was automatically unregistered. This can happen if the user uninstalls the application or, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback Service reported the APNS token as invalid.
> - The registration token expired. For example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens or the APNS token may have expired for iOS devices.
> - The client app was updated, but the new version is not configured to receive messages.
>
> For all these cases, remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages.

In order to figure out what the error is, I first need to narrow it down to one of the following four reasons. But first I have to understand what they mean.

1. **App Unregistered:** What does it mean for an app to unregister?  How can I test it?
2. **Invalid APNS token:** How can I check this?
3. **Expired token:** The tokens are brand new, so this seems unlikely, but how can I validate this?
4. **Not configured to receive messages:** It's the same app that's generating these tokens, so what else needs to be done? How can I test this?

Overall, my big question is, how can I test any one of these 4+ circumstances in which this error might be thrown? What can I do to make progress here?